# Is there any negative effects in calling the notifyDataSetChanged consecutive/several times (user-triggered)?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am extending the ArrayAdapter and I provided my own OnItemClickListener where I update certain states of my data which reflects on multiple items in the list so to update the current states of those items in the list, I am calling the notifyDataSetChanged. Its working properly as how I want it to my worry is if there are any issues or negative effects on doing so. Like when the user taps many items which results in consecutive calls to notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 1):

If the user interaction requires views to be updated then you do need to be calling `notifyDataSetChanged` each time. If you're really worried you can look at debounce algorithms but that's kind of overkill, but as long as you don't have a huge number of elements and don't add a bunch of data change listeners it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

don't worried about calling  **notifyDataSetChanged** it only notify adapter about data change